# java 8 reflection: how to iterate on a private final java.util.Vector field

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to get a reference with Java reflection to a `java.util.Vector` private variable defined in a class and iterate on it. The declaration of the variable in the class is the following: `private final Vector<Class<?>> classes = new Vector<>();`

Actually, the class from where I am trying to read the Vector is this one: [java.lang.ClassLoader](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/ClassLoader.java)

The object I need comes from this (I need to use `getSuperclass()` twice because in the application server ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() returns with a weblogic specific classloader class and the field I need comes from the parent class):

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass()
```

And the field in debug mode, I need:

[image]

A little bit about the context: the java reflection code will run in a simple servlet, deployed to an application server.

I am able to get the `java.lang.reflect.Field` with the following code:

```
Class c = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
Field classesField = c.getDeclaredField("classes");
classesField.setAccessible(true);
Type type = classesField.getGenericType();
System.out.println(type.getTypeName()); //java.util.Vector
```

Result:
[image]

But I am not able to get a reference from `java.lang.reflect.Field` to `java.util.Vector` in order to I can read the items from it.

**I have tried this ways:**

```
// 1:
Vector v = new Vector<>();
// ERROR: Can not set final java.util.Vector field java.lang.ClassLoader.classes to java.util.Vector

// 2:
public static class VectorWrapper {
    private Vector<Class<?>> v = new Vector<>();
}
VectorWrapper v = new VectorWrapper();
// ERROR: Can not set final java.util.Vector field java.lang.ClassLoader.classes to a.b.c.Test$VectorWrapper

// try to get the vector
Object o = classesField.get(v);
Vector classes = (Vector<Class<?>>) o;
System.out.println(classes.size());
```

The codes above do not work, throws exceptions.

It seems that because the field in the class is defined `final` I am not able to get the reference. Maybe I need to get the Iterator of the `Vector` instead of the `Vector` itself? But I am not sure about it.

How can I loop on this Vector field and geat the items from it?

**-- UPDATE --**

I have created a simple test application, no application server, only pure Java is used. I tried with Java 11, I only have this Java version on that machine. But I guess this behaves the same with Java 8. Just copy and paste the code, and execute it to see the exception:

```
Can not set final java.util.Vector field java.lang.ClassLoader.classes to java.util.Vector
```

**Code:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ReflectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class c = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
        printFields(c);
        printValue(c, "classes");
    }

    private static void printFields(Class c) {
        System.out.println(c.getTypeName());
        int i = 0;
        Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field m : fields) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i + ".  " + m.getType().getName() + ":" + m.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    }

    private static void printValue(Class c, String fieldName) throws Exception {
        Field classesField = c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        classesField.setAccessible(true);
        Type type = classesField.getGenericType();
        System.out.println(type.getTypeName());

        Vector v = new Vector<>();
        Object o = classesField.get(v);
        Vector classes = (Vector<Class<?>>) o;
        System.out.println(classes.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: `final` means you cannot easily __set__ the reference. The error you get occurs if you use `.set()` on a Field. This.. does not match with your story, which is that you want to read. So, just.. call `get()`, problem solved? Your actual problem is that none of this is likely to work on JDK9 and up, due to module restrictions. But  the error that would cause is not what you pasted, so, one step at a time.

Comment: I use `.get()`. I do not use `.set()`. I have checked that 10 times.

Comment: If you need a list of all loaded classes, consider using a java agent.

Comment: What do you think `classesField.get(v);` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the ClassLoader object so that you can call `classesField.get(classLoader)`. Here is some example code that may be helpful:

```
@Test
public void testVector() throws Exception {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class classLoaderClass = null;
    for (Class c = classLoader.getClass(); c != Object.class; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
        if (c == java.lang.ClassLoader.class) {
            classLoaderClass = c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("found a " + classLoaderClass.getName());
    Field classesField = classLoaderClass.getDeclaredField("classes");
    classesField.setAccessible(true);
    Type type = classesField.getGenericType();
    System.out.println(type.getTypeName()); //java.util.Vector
    Object o = classesField.get(classLoader);
    System.out.println("o is a " + o.getClass().getName());
    if (o instanceof Vector) {
        Vector v = (Vector) o;
        v.forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
        });
    }
}
```

A shorter version:

```
@Test
public void testVector2() throws Exception {
    Field classesField = java.lang.ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("classes");
    classesField.setAccessible(true);
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Vector<Class<?>> v = (Vector<Class<?>>) classesField.get(classLoader);

    System.out.println("ClassLoader has " + v.size() + " classes");
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `java.lang.reflect.Field` holds information about the class and its fields. This is only related to the class, not the object of the class. Because I need a value from a specific instance of the class, I need to pass the object to the `Field.get(...)`.